# INSTALL PARSE FAILED MANIFEST MALFORMED: Failed parse

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-emulator, manifest

I am new to Flutter & I am trying to run an existing app on VS Code. I get this error message on my terminal when I attempt to run it on the Android emulator:

```
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install
/Users/tazar/Downloads/ethereal-meditations-app-made-app-runnable/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app
.apk: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI:
/data/app/vmdl469477611.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #260):
com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver: Targeting S+ (version 31
and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are
present]
Error launching application on sdk gphone64 arm64.
```

This is my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="path">
   <application
        android:label="---"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

        <!-- FACEBOOK LOGIN -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
              android:exported="true"
              android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
          <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
              android:configChanges=
                      "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
              android:exported="true"
              android:label="@string/app_name" />
          <activity
              android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
              android:exported="true">
              <intent-filter>
                  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                  <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
              </intent-filter>
          </activity>
        <!-- END FACEBOOK LOGIN -->
        
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
            

        <!-- Sample AdMob App ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
        <!-- EM account: android:value="ca-app-pub-3706741424467059~5052028195"/> -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-3706741424467059~5052028195"/>

            <!-- android:value="ca-app-pub-8622122832922913~9459724912"/> -->
            <!-- android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/> -->


    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>


</manifest>
```

The app runs fine on the browser, but not on the emulator. When I attempted to solve this issue, everywhere I looked, I was told to add "android:exported='true'" to each activity. I made those changes, but I still get the same error. I am kinda stuck now & I don't know what to do. Please feel free to share your thoughts, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Does your `com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver` declare `android:exported`?

Comment: I don't believe I have a "com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver"

Comment: This may from `flutter_local_notifications` dependency,  you should check update for it, and have you update your `compileSdkVersion`? If still doesn't work, you may have to find it and add that attribute.

Answer (score 2):

you have to follow these rules to migrate from targetSdk 30 to 31
https://developer.android.com/google/play/requirements/target-sdk#pre12

As far as I see it your manifest is missing this point

> Intent filters: If your app contains activities, services, or
> broadcast receivers that use intent filters, you must explicitly
> declare the android:exported attribute for these components.